# How to update/delete ref value in VueJS 3 composition api?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I'm using a ref value to be able to only execute a click event if the ref value is changing.

For example, if I want to update/del the array inside `let myRef = ref([]);`, do I just drill inside the proxy and do the operations like that :

```js
selectedElements.value.push(3);
```

which returns
`Proxy {0: 3}`

or what is the correct way to update/del the `ref.value` ?

```js
export default {  
  setup() {
    let myRef = ref([]);
    return {
     myRef
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: please clarify more

Answer (score 1):

You've got it under control. This is how I manage state.

In setup, I list all of my refs or reactive objects.  I'll use computed properties if I feel like it to do various crosschecks on my refs or state, e.g. do I have records, how many, etc.

I'll write small functions that will handle state changes/mutations in a local component.  If I need to use a watcher on state (ref or reactive object), then I'll do that and use it to call a method/action.  You can only update ref inner values by accessing the ref object's single property .value which points to its inner value.  I'm sure you know this, but the ref is a wrapper.  IN your setup method, you'll got to unwrap a ref to change its inner value, but this isn't true with a reactive object - wherein you can just set that value as per a normal Vue2 data value.

So, yes, in your example, you can mutate your myRef array however you need by accessing its value property.  Again, a good way to do this would be to define a method that does the thing that you need done, adding to the array.  And, use a computed property to check for whatever it is that is your conditional that is allowing or denying your click event.

Answer (score 0):

```
const datas=ref({
  id:0,
  name:'test',
  age:20
})

delete datas.value.id
console.log(datas.value) //{name:'test',age:20}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.